# Unable to resolve module `some-name` from `Path/To/Project/script.js`

Tags: react-native

I tried to `require("some-name");` in my `script.js`. This gave me the following error:

> Unable to resolve module `some-name` from `Path/To/Project/script.js`: Module does not exist in the module map.

So I removed the `require("some-name");` in the `script.js`. The same error occurred.
So I went to a previous state of the app. The error keeps happening and there is nowhere in the code that I request the "some-name" file nor I have the file in my directory.

Here an image where I search in my code to the old file name:
[image]

The screen shot of the error in react-native.
[image]
I tried the steps shown in the error message and it did not resolve the problem.

It is possible to add more information if it is unclear.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall app, reinstall node module and restarted server?

Comment: Also confirm that the module you are trying to access is there on shown path. There might be typo also.

Comment: @NikhilParmar I do not try to access that module in my project. It was a file in my directory witch is removed.

Comment: @NikhilParmar I did try to uninstall the app and restart the server but it results in the same error.

Comment: Did you try to find that file name in you whole project directory? It might be possible that you missed to remove that file from any file OR may be calling from cached folder.

Comment: @NikhilParmar I think the project that is running is a cached folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168836/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-rensvwalstijn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the cache.

This problem was fixed by:

1. renaming the file where the error came from.
2. restarting the server.

Due to the file renaming the server took the updated project with out the error. This problem was solved with the help of [Nikhil Parmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5064375/nikhil-parmar) in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168836/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-rensvwalstijn).

The error was already fixed in the code but the server still used the cached project. A normal cache clear and server restart did not work.